# Child Kotlin test class runs all parent tests

Tags: intellij-idea, junit, kotlin

I am using Kotlin and JUnit. I have a parent test abstract class which contains some test implementations and also some abstract tests.

```
@Test
abstract fun testThis()

@Test
fun testThat() {
    assert(true)
}
```

In my child class I have the implementation of `testThis()`.

```
@Test
override fun testThis() {
    assert(1 == 1)
}
```

And in another child class I have another implementation:

```
@Test
override fun testThis() {
    assert(2 == 3)
}
```

However, when I run all tests from IntelliJ, I can see that `testThat()` was called twice, once in each child.

How do I stop that from happening? I want the tests to be run only once, as part of their respective classes (in this case, `testThat()` should be executed once, in the parent class). Is my design problematic?

Comment: I'm trying to reproduce this, but cannot, I only get one execution of the test method, could you include a full code sample

Comment: I corrected my question

Answer (score 1):

I would keep your parent class for the common test utilities and setup, and move `testThat` to a separate test class.

If you only want it to run once, if you want it in both test classes when they are ran individually then you could explicitly skip it if you define a test suite for running all your tests, and only leave it ran on the parent test.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion your design is indeed problematic. Even if we could possibly eliminate invoking testThat() in parent, if you declare another child you'll have two runs of the same test anyway. I feel like inheritance here is very uneccessary. Why do you actually want to extend another test class?
I sometimes do inheritance on test classes but without actual tests implementations in parent class (abstract test though is ok).

Comment: I don't mind having two runs of the same test if their implementation is different.

Comment: I corrected my question: there was one execution for each child

Comment: This is how inheritance work. If each child inherits test from parent it will be invoked. Therefore you should think about some design change. Perhaps some abstract class with only abstract test and without actual test implementations. Perhaps testThat() could go to another class. If it is dependent on some common methods (which your  children also use) that another class should become another child.